# XCode Analyzer Warnings Without Details / Line Numbers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, clang-static-analyzer

I ran the analyzer and found a handful of warnings that I can't associate with lines in the code. I'm not sure how to handle them. Clicking on them brings me to the right file in the editor, but the analyzer summary results tell me that much. I don't know what each of these is referring to, and going through the code line-by-line is not productive (I don't know what I'm looking for).

```
Object with +0 retain counts returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected

Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller

Object with +0 retain counts returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected

Object sent -autorelease too many times
```

For the last warning, I removed the autorelease, and it went away, but I don't know how to release it, since it's used in a return statement.

```
- (Client*) createNewClient {
...
    Client *client = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Client"inManagedObjectContext:dataInterface.managedObjectContext];        
...
    return client;
}
```

What do I do with these, in general?

Answer (score 0):

As you are not owning the object that is returned by `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:`, you do not have to release it.

From the [Apple Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html):

> You take ownership of an object if you
>   create it using a method whose name
>   begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or
>   “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc,
>   newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you
>   send it a retain message.

`insertNewObjectForEntityForName:` contains 'New', but does not begin with it.

Answer (score 0):

this may be a flagged for naming conventions. if you want to return an autoreleased object, try renaming it to:

```
- (Client *)clientWithCurrentContext
```